# How to create a regex that will find a substring of a complex URL

Tags: regex, go

Need some guidance on creating a regex that will identify part of the URL.

```
URL1: test-project-233-TEST-ENDPOINT.test.as.ds.abcdefg.com
URL2: test-project-124-ENDPOINT.test.dd.ad.gf.abcdefg.com
```

The goal is to build a regex that can parse out "test-project-233" and "test-project-124" for me.

I've already tried to google around and finding complex regex differentiation. It would be awesome to get some pointers on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Well, what do you want to do with the matching text, extract, replace?

Comment: No, I want to extract the test project name `test-project-233` for example. Not from slicing but dynamically extract it

Answer (score 4):

A regexp is not needed.  Just slice off the start of the string:

```
for _, s := range []string{
    "test-project-233-TEST-ENDPOINT.test.as.ds.abcdefg.com",
    "test-project-124-ENDPOINT.test.dd.ad.gf.abcdefg.com",
} {
    fmt.Println(s[:16])
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/rtoQ7hLpmVJ

Comment: Thanks for that, but this only make sense for urls that has a fixed size of names etc. This is not dynamic enough. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 2):

The regex would be `([a-z]*-){2}\d*`. In order to simplify your research, go on https://regexr.com/ and past your links in. From there you will be able to create your regex step by step easily.